# Open folder in root of project with Java Runtime

Tags: java, runtime

I want to open the folder `bestellingen` with windows explorer. the folder is in the root directory of my project.
so far I have this:

```
        Runtime rs = Runtime.getRuntime();
        try {
            Process p = rs.exec("./bestellingen/");
        } catch (IOException exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But if I run the project the error says "acces denied"

Comment: yes, you cant execute a directory, what OS are you running?

Comment: what do you want to do inside the folder?

Comment: @La-comadreja I want to open the folder in windows Explorer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directories can't be executed but you could do

```
File dir = new File("...");
if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
    Desktop.getDesktop().open(dir);
}
```